# Firebase clearTimeout not stop the setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can I stop a setTimeout function before starting from the onWrite event on a "Firebase Cloud Function"? I try with setTimeout, but the clearTimeout do not stop the setTimeout.

P.S.: I've already raised the script timeout from the Firebase panel from 60 seconds (default) to 360 seconds.

```
var timeOutOnline = {};
exports.online = functions.database.ref('/server/{serverId}/online/time').onWrite(event => {
    const serverId = event.params.serverId;
    var time = event.data.val();
    var lastDateOnline = new Date( time * 1000);
    var dateString = lastDateOnline.toGMTString();

    clearTimeout(timeOutOnline[serverId]);

    refGet = db.ref('/server/'+serverId+'/online/');
    refGet.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            var onlineSnap = snapshot.val();
            if (onlineSnap && onlineSnap.alarm == true) {
                    sendMail(serverId,false, 'not responding' , 'Server '+ serverId + ' not responding from '+dateString);
                    setAlarmStatus(serverId,false);
            } else {
                    timeOutOnline[serverId] = setTimeout(function() {
                            sendMail(serverId,true, 'not responding' , 'Server '+ serverId + ' not responding from '+dateString);
                            setAlarmStatus(serverId,true);
                    }, 21000);
            }

    });
    return true;
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Now I use promise, but clearTimeout still not working, not clearing setTimeout function. What am I doing wrong?

```
var timeOutOnline = {};
exports.online = functions.database.ref('/server/{serverId}/online/time').onWrite(event => {
    const serverId = event.params.serverId;
    var time = event.data.val();
    var lastDateOnline = new Date( time * 1000);
    var dateString = lastDateOnline.toGMTString();

    console.log(v);

    if(!timeOutOnline[serverId]) {
            timeOutOnline[serverId] = [];
    } else {
            timeOutOnline[serverId].length;
            for (var i = 0; i < timeOutOnline[serverId].length; i++) {
                    if (timeOutOnline[serverId][i]) {
                            timeOutOnline[serverId][i].cancel();
                            timeOutOnline[serverId][i] = null;
                    }
            }
    }

    timeOutOnline[serverId] = timeOutOnline[serverId].filter(n => n);

    refGet = db.ref('/server/'+serverId+'/online/');
    refGet.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            var onlineSnap = snapshot.val();
            if (onlineSnap && onlineSnap.alarm == true) {
                    sendMail(serverId,false, 'not responding' , 'Server '+ serverId + ' not responding from '+dateString);
                    setAlarmStatus(serverId,false);
            } else {
                    timeOutOnline[serverId].push(waitForServer(210000));
                    var index = timeOutOnline[serverId].length - 1;

                    return timeOutOnline[serverId][index].promise.then(function(i) {
                            console.log('Server '+ serverId + ' not responding from '+dateString);
                            sendMail(serverId,true, 'not responding' , 'Server '+ serverId + ' not responding from '+dateString);
                            setAlarmStatus(serverId,true);

                    });
            }

    });

    return true;
});


function waitForServer(ms) {
    var timeout, promise;

    promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    resolve('timeout done');
            }, ms);
    });

    return {
            promise:promise,
            cancel:function(){
                    console.log('cancel timeout: '+timeout);
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
    };
}
```

Comment: That should work fine, assuming the timeout exists by the time it's being stopped, and that key in the timeOutOnline hasn't been overridden (which isn't necessarily impossible given your code, since there's a delay between clearing any existing and starting the new one)

Comment: It is possibile that Firebase clean `timeOutOnline` array?

Comment: haha, no, that would be magic

Answer (score -1):

There's a lot of things wrong in this function.

First of all, it's not clear to me why you want to use setTimeout() in this function.  In fact, there are almost no valid use cases for setTimeout() with Cloud Functions.  Functions are supposed to execute as fast as possible, and setTimeout only really just incurs extra cost to your processing.  Cloud Functions does not enable you to run "background work" that survives past the invocation of the function - that's just not how it works.

Second of all, you're performing async work here, but you're not [returning a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) to indicate when that work completes.  If you don't return a promise that's resolved when your work completes, your function is highly likely to exhibit strange problems, including work not completing as you'd expect.

Comment: I understand that using timeouts in Firebase can be expensive or wrong, but the application is small and not public, I use only to monitoring our servers. 

I tried to use the promises, but I'm probably wrong.I have updated the original post.

Comment: You're still not returning a promise from the function.  You're returning `true`.  Please explain why it is that you need to use setTimeout and what you expect this function to do.

Comment: All my servers write on Firebase database every some minutes, every time one server write on db, the script clean active timeout. If timeout function will run, the server is probably offline and send me a notification.

Comment: Cloud Functions isn't going to work for what you're trying to do. If you need to monitor your servers, you should be using some other dedicated monitoring tool.